# HTML | Высoта div по контенту

Tags: html

```
<div style="max-width: 745px;margin-left: 7px;display: block;">
<input style="float:left;margin:0 5px;min-width: 27px;margin-top:5px;" name="page" type="submit" value="1">
<input style="float:left;margin:0 5px;min-width: 27px;margin-top:5px;" name="page" type="submit" value="2">
<input style="float:left;margin:0 5px;min-width: 27px;margin-top:5px;" name="page" type="submit" value="3">
</div>
```

Выглядит вот так и  при этом по высоте не расширяется по контенту. Я хочу сделать отступ от последнего элемента, чтобы внизу был отступ. Видите как прилипает:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Хочу чтобы после 24 был пробел (отступ снизу),
br не помогает

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете добавить минимальную высоту (например, 100 пикселей) к родительскому блоку с 24 input полями, и он не прилипнет к низу

P.S: тег `<br>` выполняет только перенос строки, не добавляет свободного места внизу.

```
.all-inputs{
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

Или вы можете использовать `margin-bottom` для родительского элемента.

Надеюсь, я помог вам :)